# Injectivity trajectory to set singular control to zero

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems, control-theory, optimal-control

Consider a control system of the form
$$
\dot x(t) = X(x(t)) + u(t)\, Y(x(t)) \qquad \qquad (*)
$$
where $X,Y$ are two smooth vector fields, and $u$ is the (bounded measurable) control function.

Take a trajectory $x(\cdot)$ and a control $u(\cdot)$ solution of $(*)$ for $t\in [0,T]$ and such that $Y(x(t))=0$ on $[0,T]$.

---

It is stated that if $x(\cdot)$ is analytic and injective, then we can assume that $x(\cdot)$ is associated to $u\equiv 0$.

Why do we need the injectivity or analycity of the trajectory ? 
I would have said: any control function can be candidate since $Y(x(t))=0$.

EDIT: In fact we are interested in a system of the form :
$$
\dot z = H_X(z(t)) + u(t)\, H_Y(z(t))
$$
where $z(t)=(x(t),p(t))$ satisfies $H_Y(z(t))=0$.

The remaining question:
Why to we need the injectivity of $x(\cdot)$ to state that
we can consider the zero control to be associated to $x(\cdot)$.

[Source p.113 in the middle of the page](https://sci-hub.tw/https://doi.org/10.1515/form.1993.5.111)

Comment: Can you give a link to the source where it is stated that $u\equiv0$?

Comment: I added in the first post

Comment: My french is not the best, but I do not see anywhere stated that $Y(x(t))=0$.

Comment: The sentence : "Considérons maintenant une trajectoire singulière de reference $\gamma$ [...]" means:
Consider a reference singular trajectory.

Such trajectory satisfies (0.4) and the condtion $\frac{\partial H}{\partial u}=0$ yields $Y(\gamma(t))=0$.

Comment: The Hamiltonian seems to be defined as $<p,X(x(t))+u(t)\,Y(x(t))>$ which is the same as $p^\top \left(X(x(t))+u(t)\,Y(x(t))\right)$. $H_u=p^\top Y(x(t))=0$, so $Y(x(t))$ has to be perpendicular to the co-state.

Comment: You are absolutely right ! 
now it's $(x,p)$ which is solution to the Hamiltonian system defined by $H(x,p)=H_X(x,p) + u\,H_Y(x,p)$ where $H_X=p\cdot X(x)$ and $H_Y=p\cdot Y(x)$ and such that $H_Y(x(t),p(t))=0$ and they state they can set $u\equiv 0$.

Comment: .... if $x(\cdot)$ is injective and analytic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution, I see why now it's not obvious.

[image: Solution]